# How Can I add a JDBC data source connect to Hive?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, hive

I'm trying to add a new JDBC Data Source connect to hive in oracle BI publisher, I know how to connect to hive using JDBC but the problem is Oracle BI publisher doesn't accept blank Username. How Can I create a data source without input username in Oracle BI publisher?
Connection detail:

driverName = org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Connection String jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
Username:
Password:
error: A value must be entered for "Username".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Hive JDBC driver does not rely on the username/password for authorizing the connection, so you can pretty much put any values in those fields.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try what you suggest!